# Using a variable in a range statement in VBA excell macro

Tags: vba, excel

Ok, I'm sure this question is really basic but all my searchers turn up complicated answers and I've been messing with VBA for about a day.  I have two worksheets in an excel doc, I've created a button that I can click that invokes my macro that is just moving cells from one work sheet to another.  But I need my macro to determine what row I am on.  I'm using this:

```
r = ActiveCell.Row
```

to determine my row, but what would be the easiest way to use that variable in a range statement like this:

```
Range("A2").Select
```

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking, though. The way I read is: "how do I select the row from the variable `r`?" but it's not clear that is really your question.

Comment: [Stop using .select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Answer (score 8):

You could use the Range method with the & operator to join the variable into a string:

```
Range("A" & r)
```

Alternately you can use the Cells method which takes arguments *(Row, Column)*:

```
Cells(r, "A")
```